# Python - AWS Lambda not waiting for subprocess finish

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scrapy, aws-lambda

I'm trying to execute the following code on AWS lambda:

```
from os import listdir
from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(datetime.now())
    call('sh scp.sh', shell=True)
    print(listdir('/tmp/stores'))
    print(datetime.now())
```

The `scp.sh` script execute a copy files from other server, but the problem is, the main thread is not waiting for the `subprocess` finishes.

This is the output:

```
START RequestId: 6241a143-8c5f-11e8-9d42-d330bf352385 Version: $LATEST
2018-07-20 20:56:33.568496
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/stores': FileNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    print(listdir('/tmp/stores'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/stores'
```

This is the source of `scp.sh` file:

```
ssh-add nextcloud-key.pem;
scp -r ubuntu@34.218.106.211:/tmp/stores /tmp/stores;
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the scp command is failing and nothing gets copied to /tmp. Instead of `subprocess.call`, use `subprocess.check_call` and you'll see that it raises an exception.